Cant install any package in Kali Linux on WSL due to libc6:amd64
I recently created a wsl 2 environment and i am running Kali Linux on it. When trying to install metapackages, the installation process gets stuck at Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.37-15) ... indefinitely and doesn't proceed further. I have tried fixing broken packages, checking for conflicting packages, forcing install, trying to manually install, re-installing Kali on WSL, and then re-installing the entire WSL environment. But, regardless, the problem seems to persist.
To be more specific, this is the error message I got when trying to install nmap using apt:
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.37-15) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Either I get an error message similar to the one above or it just gets indefinitely stuck at Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.37-15) ...

Can you add the info from Settings --> System --> About, specifically Processor and System Type

@eyoung100 Yeah sure.
Processor: AMD Ryzen 3 5425U with Radeon Graphics            2.70 GHz
System Type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Now check your firmware.  Make sure Virtualization is enabled, and that you haven't accidently installed a 32-bit WSL on a 64-bit system.

@eyoung100 Hi. Yes, I have double checked my virtualization and if i have 64-bit WSL. I have also successfully operated VMs on this computer.

Can you install a plain Debian/Ubuntu in a VM real quick, and attempt installing a meta-package?  Let's see if the problem just exists in the Kali install or stretches between VM's

@eyoung100 Hi. I tried installing metapackages in a VM. Fortunately, there wasn't any problems doing so. So, the problems are only limited to this particular system. However, I re-installed the Kali on the WSL environment one more time, but this time i tried to install a single application instead of a metapackage and it went smoothly. However, I was met with the same issue when i tried to install another application.

Does This help?

There is a known bug in systemd 255.3 (I only found this while browsing trough questions at AskUbuntu).
See Debian bug 1060387, and this discussion on the WSL repository, which leads to the following fix:
echo '[boot] systemd=true' >> /etc/wsl.conf
sudo mv /usr/sbin/telinit /usr/sbin/telinit.bak && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/true /usr/sbin/telinit

The above code does the following:

Informs WSL that systemd will always be the default init system until the instance is destroyed.
Fools WSL into thinking that telinit is always running by linking it to true.


Thank you so much! Although writing '[boot] systemd=true' to /etc/wsl.conf didn't work for me, I was able to find an alternative solution in the links you provided. Everything works perfectly now!

@AnirudhMurthy Modifying wsl.conf is a configuration update.  You won't see any noticeable change.  The needed change is the second line of code.

Ah, I see. But either way the issue is solved and I am not facing any trouble now.
